# Large spaces left between pages in a thesis

Tags: vertical-spacing

I have a lot of white empty space left between two pages(or several) in the same thesis and I want to eliminate it if it is possible.
This is an image of the problem, on the other page is another diagram and I  am guessing the problem is in how the space is divided. I use Overleaf and a  tex model given by my university.

[image: example of empty space]

I have been struggling with this for a while now, and the only solution I found was to write more text to fill up the empty space or scale down images to fit in the empty space.

Comment: Did you try adding to your preamble the directive `\raggedbottom`? (The  default is `\flushbottom`.)

Comment: I did, it wasn't helpful, it left too big spaces in the bottom of the pages, even to the pages that were normal.

Comment: Could you post a complete code reproducing the problem?

Comment: Unexplained large spaces usually are the result of large unbreakable boxes, such as minipages  tabulars, pictures and the [H] option of the float package.